# .vbs script runs in batch file but not when run through task scheduler

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, windows-task-scheduler

I have a batch script with 4 commands as follows

```
sqlcmd (truncate table in database)

del "path to existing csv to delete"

"path to my .vbs script" "file path to xls file to convert" "file path to where csv is to be created"

"File path to Python" "File path to python script to read csv into database"
```

It runs just fine when I double click the batch file. When I try to run the batch file from the command prompt it doesn't see the .csv file to delete, I'm not sure why this is, but I don't think it matters for my purposes.

When I run the task from task scheduler manually it truncates the table in the database and deletes the existing csv file but the new one is not created which leads me to believe it is getting stuck on the .vbs file.

I have tried making an individual task with the .vbs script and passing in the path to the .xls and .csv files as arguments, but again it just runs without stopping.

I have tried adding

```
@echo off
>log.txt(
the body of my batch script
)
```

but nothing gets written to the log. I have also tried adding cscript and also tried adding wscript at the beginning of the line in the batch file which calls the .vbs script and have tried changing the start in directory to C:\batch where the file resides.

No luck with any of the above attempts. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Try adding some `MsgBox("Start of Script")` lines in the VBS file to see if it runs the script at all, and then add more to see how far it gets.

Also, I'd check that the batch file is executed with Administrator privileges. When you open a Command Prompt, usually it isn't. You have to right-click on the Command Prompt in Start Menu and chose "Run as administrator".

Comment: I would add a space character, from `>log.txt(` to `>log.txt (`.

Comment: Added the ```MsgBox("Start of Script")``` the message pops up when double clicked as batch file. I am running the command prompt as an administrator.

Comment: @Compo tried what you suggested. Still no output written.

Comment: I made a little head way maybe by adding ```cscript.exe``` in front of the line in the batch file which calls the .vbs script. It completes now, but the file isn't copied over to the csv. The log output simple states"
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [this 2013 answer](https://superuser.com/questions/579900/why-cant-excel-open-a-file-when-run-from-task-scheduler/655458#655458) by [eric](https://superuser.com/users/260499/eric) on Superuser:

> Create these two folders:
>
> 32Bit:
>
> ```
> C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
> ```
>
> 64Bit:
>
> ```
> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
> ```
>
> Excel needs these folders if it's not run interactively. Create both folders even if you are on a 64-bit OS.